# Ordinary Differential Equation IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ \frac{y}{x}+ (y^3-\log(x))\frac{dy}{dx}=0 \\  y(1)=\sqrt{2}$

I have the IVP above and I'm trying to solve it, I know that $y=k\log(|x|); k \in \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of the similar linear-homogeneous equation $\frac{y}{x} -\log(x)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ but this doesn't seem to help me find the solution of this problem. Any suggestions?

EDIT: $ 
\frac{y}{x}+(y^3-log(x))\frac{dy}{dx}  =0 \ (v=log(x))  \rightarrow  
 \\ y\frac{dv}{dx}+(y^3-v)\frac{dy}{dx} =0 \ \ (\ast) \rightarrow \\
\frac{dv}{dy}y+y^3-v=0 \rightarrow \\ 
\frac{dv}{dy}+y^2-\frac{v}{y}=0 \rightarrow \\
\frac{d(\frac{v}{y})}{dy}=-y \rightarrow \\
\frac{v(x)}{y}-\frac{log(1)}{1}=-\frac{y^2}{2}+1;
$

$$ \frac{log(x)}{y}+\frac{y^2}{2}=1$$

How can I justify the step ($\ast$)?

Comment: Set $t=\log x$ and reverse the dependency. On first glance, this should result in a linear DE for $t(y)$.

Comment: How could one arrive at the solution in the implicit form?

Comment: What do you mean? Lutz Lehmann showed how to transform the ODE into a linear one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step $(*)$ follows from the chain rule. By substituting $v=\log x$, the derivative w.r.t. the new variable is obtained from

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac1x \frac{dy}{dv}$$

so that

$$\frac yx + \left(y^3 - \log x\right) \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \\
\implies y + \left(y^3-\log x\right) x\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \\
\implies y + \left(y^3-v\right) \frac{dy}{dv} = 0$$

and from here you can extract a linear ODE in $v(y)$ and hence the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your observation; how could I extract the linear ODE without simply "multiplying by $\frac{dv}{dy}$", I guess that I didn't understand this concept yet. How should a more formal approach to it be?

Comment: That's known as the [inverse function rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_rule). Rather than multiplying by a derivative, you simply rewrite the derivative in terms of its reciprocal. (Bear in mind terms and conditions for applying the rule.)